# R Shiny "Not found" error in iframe for viewing PDF from local machine

Tags: r, iframe, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to display a pdf file, which is stored in **www** folder.

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(tabItem(tabName = "test", 
                        tabBox(tags$iframe(style='height:400px; width:100%; scrolling=yes',
                                           src="www/test.pdf"))))
)

server <- function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I run `file.exists("www/test.pdf")`, the answer is TRUE.

The `www` folder is placed in the same directory as `app.r` file.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong and maybe don't understand how to display the file that is stored on a local disc and not on the web. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the problem. I should only put:

```
dashboardBody(tabItem(tabName = "test", 
                    tabBox(tags$iframe(style='height:400px; width:100%; scrolling=yes',
                                       src="test.pdf")
```

**src** argument should be without **www/**